# Prove that the following is an identity

Tags: trigonometry

$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cot(x)} + \cos(x) = \sec(x)$

Note that this involves identities, so you can't treat it like an equation and multiply both sides by a number. ( when I multiplied both sides by $\cos(x)$, it turned out I could easily use the pathagorean identity, but the solution obtained was WRONG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin}{\cot}+\cos =\frac{\sin}{\frac{\cos}{\sin}}+\cos = \frac{\sin^2}{\cos} + \cos = \frac{\overbrace{\sin^2+\cos^2}^{=1}}{\cos} = \frac{1}{\cos} = \sec$$

Comment: The question seems a lot like homework. Please do not reveal the complete answer - rather, give a hint.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, I side with "Lord Soth". If people are stuck on problems of this difficulty, it is likely that no hints will help. It is best to show a complete solution as they will likely have many additional problems to do. I would only refrain from doing so, if - and it would then be obvious - they are asking a lot of questions.

Comment: How is equation involving trig functions different from a normal equation?

Comment: @user139024 Sorry, I do not understand what you exactly mean by your question. Can you elaborate? A trigonometric equation is no different than a normal equation, equation is an equation :)

Comment: Notice if I multiply both sides by cosx, it would also work. But this is a invalid approach, why?

Comment: @user139024, That is not invalid. With that you can still prove that the identity is true. But since you modified both sides you're going away to transforming left side to the original right side and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you mean "equivalent to a well-known identity", here's a helpful hint:

**Hint:** $$\dfrac{\sin x}{\cot x}+\cos x=\sec x\\
\implies \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x}+\cos x=\dfrac{1}{\cos x}\\
\implies \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x}+\dfrac{\cos^2 x}{\cos x}=\dfrac{1}{\cos x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Working from the expression on the left, we have:

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cot x}+\cos x=\frac{\sin x+\cos x\cot x}{\cot x} =\frac{\sin x+\cos x\cdot \displaystyle\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}{\cot x}=$$
$$=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x }{\sin x}}{\cot x}=\frac{1}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{1}{\cot x}=\frac{1}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x. $$

Then, the equality follow, i.e.,
$$ \frac{\sin x}{\cot x}+\cos x=\sec x.$$